# Web - How to not disable but hide the scroll in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

My website is available [here](http://danyl.io/about.html).

Problem is that I'm getting a double scroll because I used an `iframe` to display content in each page of my website.

I tried this:

```
<iframe ... scrollable="no"></iframe>
```

and also tried to override the default css by using !important:

```
.fancybox-overlay, .fancybox-overlay-fixed {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

But nothing is working.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about making your parent element fit the page so that the only scrollbar is the one inside the `iFrame` and not the other way?

You can do something like this:

```css
.fit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0
}

.Parent {
  border: 2px solid red
}

iframe {
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='Parent fit'>
    <iframe class='fit' src='http://stackoverflow.com'></iframe>
  </div>
</body>
```

#### Note:

- Green border is the iframe
- Red border is the parent container

Comment: Thank you mate! It seems to be working like a charm :D

How now to hide the grey color element of scrollbar please ?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: In that case [***refer here***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280645/how-to-style-the-scrollbar-of-on-iframe): It isn't possible unless you style the scrollbar on the source of the iframe itself (or use a js lib).

Comment: In any case, if this helped you out. Make sure to upvote and mark as accepted, so others can benefit from this answer as well!

Comment: Sure. Thank you very much for your help buddy!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **scrolling** attribute not **scrallable**.

source https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_scrolling.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<iframe src="https://bing.com" 
        class="this" 
        scrolling="no" >
</iframe>
```

```css
.this {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="http://bing.com" 
        class="this" 
        scrolling="no" >
</iframe>
```