# IE11 - Scrollbar flickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, internet-explorer-11

my web application has an  and a SideNav (left) and horizontal Navigation on top.

The height of the  is always based on the height of the loaded content. I have a "resizeMe" function for that.

But now I have the problem that the scroll bar flickers briefly when loading (of the iFrame) and then disappears again. Is there a way to make the scrollbar disappear by default in IE11?

I have already tried the following attributes on the :

```
<iframe name="Source" 
        id="Source" 
        src="" 
        frameborder="0" 
        scrolling="" 
        style="height: 905px; overflow: hidden; -ms-overflow-style: none;" 
        onload="resizeMe()">
</iframe>
```

*height is calculated*

Thanks! :)

Comment: I know its not your solution, but IE was always a mess. No longer support from Microsoft to IE, so no further consideration from me. I love my life as webdesigner without internet Explorer, you will too ;)

Comment: yeah IE sucks, but I am forced to use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having a site, which embeds another page,whose scrollbars are hidden and even do not show in IE 11(while loading). And the codes, I have used in the embedded site are:

- `scrollbar-width:none;`
- `-ms-overflow-style:none;`(You have used this, try the others)
- `::-webkit-scrollbar{width:0}`
  You have used `overflow:hidden;` which not only hides the scrollbar but also disables scrolling, so using `-ms-overflow-style:none;` would be useless if you want to disable scrolling as you have already used `overflow:hidden;`. And the above codes hide the scroll-bar, but enables scrolling(unlike `overflow:hidden;`)
  **I would recommend you, that if you have embedded a site, which is owned by you, then try putting these codes in your embedded site.**
   And I do not think that scrollbar style of iframe will be followed in major browsers according to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280645/how-to-style-the-scrollbar-of-on-iframe#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20cross%2Dbrowser,you%20load%20in%20the%20iframe.).